# How to close sweet alert automatically after 5 seconds in react

Tags: reactjs

How to close sweet alert after five seconds automatically?

This is one.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import swal from 'sweetalert';


const App = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => { swal('Registered successfully'); }} className='btn btn-danger'>Click here</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is one.css

```
.swal-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `timer`

Something like this:

```
 swal({text:'Registered successfully', timer: 5000});
```